# Jquery Not able to fetch changed value of input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fetch the changed input filed value using jquery which is getting changed javascript event of drop down select.
I simply am not getting where exactly the things are getting wrong. It is something related to dom tree refresh (.live)? Any help/suggestions would be great. Thanks.

```
/* adding the value to user_val input field id in javascript onload function based on drop down select event*/
document.getElementById('user_val').Value = "abcd";


/* then trying to get value which changed  */
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#submits").click(function() {        
              alert($("#user_val").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your `click` event handler function. Change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#submits").click(function() {        
              alert($("#user_val").val());
          });
});
```

And change `Value` to `value` (note the lowercase "v"), and then it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors you got there:

1. You should use `document.getElementById('user_val').value = "abcd";` and not `document.getElementById('user_val').Value = "abcd";` (lower case `value`, not `Value`).
2. You should also close the ready event after your click event.
3. [Here is the complete working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/uYwKz/):

   ```
   /* adding the value to user_val input field id in javascript onload function based on drop down select event*/
   document.getElementById('user_val').value = "abcd";

   /* then trying to get value which changed  */
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#submits").click(function() {
           alert($("#user_val").val());
       });
   });
   ```